# Get the locale aware default format string of moment().format()

Tags: momentjs

The `moment().format('L')` returns date formatted as per set locale. For example, by default, it will return `01/31/2019` for `en` and `31/01/2019` for `fr`. I need to get that format (such as `MM/DD/YYYY` for `en` and `DD/MM/YYYY` for `fr`). How to get that format from moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use moment [`localeData`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/locale-data/) and `longDateFormat` to get locale aware format tokens used by moment.

Here a live sample:

```js
console.log( moment.localeData('en').longDateFormat('L') ); // MM/DD/YYYY
console.log( moment.localeData('fr').longDateFormat('L') ); // DD/MM/YYYY
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Don't forget to load required locales in your enviroment (see [i18n](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/) section).

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is accessible via [creationData](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/creation-data/):

```js
console.log(moment().creationData().locale._longDateFormat.L)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
```